This Rabbeinu Bachaye on not saying all of Hashem's middot - why do we say them all now?
This Rabbeinu Bachaye explains how Moshe only used certain middot of Hashem's 13 Middot of Rachamim, to gain forgiveness for the sin of the spies. Some of the middot didn't apply for that sin, and would make things worse if they were mentioned.
Nowadays, we say all of the middot, such as in Selichot. Why are we able to?

Perhaps who are we to decide which middot are necessary and which aren’t? Moshe, fine, but us?

@CuriousYid Rabbeinu Bachaye is saying that Moshe is teaching us how to pray. Also, if we are on such a low level, then how can we say more than he said in this case?

By selichot i don't see the issue. Moshe is praying here for forgiveness of a specific sin, when we pray in Selichot we are asking for forgiveness for a lot more than just one sin.

@y_g we are praying for lots of specific sins. If anything, the problem should be worse

@RabbiKaii exactly why we would need all of them

@y_g did you learn the Rabbeinu Bachaye before making this statement? Because there is an issue (several) inside that you are not addressing

@RabbiKaii I don’t understand the issue with my statement. Perhaps R Bachayeh is suggesting that when one is structuring a prayer of forgiveness for a specific sin only certain attributes should be invoked. When the Anshei Knesses HaGedolah authored the Prayers that we have, and the others that authored the Selichos, they went with the complete version, as they are for forgiveness for a whole host of sins not a particular one. Maybe I missed a part of the R Bachayeh that you are referring to

@RabbiKaii, if you are referring to the part of the R Bachayeh where he writes that certain ones are only invoked for those who are confident that their merits exceed their demerits, I understand your question. In your question it seemed to be more focused on the reasons for individual sins, which was what I was addressing in my previous comments

@y_g how does my question focus on those?

@RabbiKaii, "Some of the middot didn't apply for that sin, and would make things worse if they were mentioned" I guess I focused more on the beginning part of the sentence. I would add a quote and explain the part of the R Bachayeh you are specifically referring to in your question. It is a sizeable piece.
